# Selecting multiple elements according to ids to get the largest group that are next to one another

Tags: javascript, html, svg, frontend, custom-data-attribute

This probably sounds confusing - i have confused my self writing it ha. So basically i have some svg paths that all have Ids like 20_11_3 which is blockID_rowId_seatId.

```
<svg>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_11_1"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_11_2"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="20_11_3"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="20_11_4"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_11_5"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_11_6"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="20_11_7"></path>

  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_1"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_2"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_3"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_4"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="20_12_5"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_6"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_7"></path>

  <path class="seat" data-id="21_1_1"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="21_1_2"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="21_1_3"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="21_1_4"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="21_1_5"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="21_1_6"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="21_1_7"></path>
</svg>
```

I need grab the group of seats that have the most seats next to another another. So this case above the selection would be a node list of the three available seats in block 21 row 1.

I guess i am going to have to start by selecting all of the seat.is-available seats using querySelector all and then filtering through them to get the best group of up-to 4 seats. Really struggling to figure out how to go about it without over engineering it to death.

Hope this all makes sense.

Comment: is the group need to be adjacent ???

Comment: They need to be next to one another or at least in the same row and block.

Comment: Keep in mind i want to take a look at the entire svg and all the blocks and rows and grab a group that has the most seats together. So if there is lots of single available seats on diffrent rows but in one row there is two next to eat other i want to just then select them two seats.

Comment: if 2 groups with same size availabe ?

Comment: If there are groups that have the same size just one of them groups if fine

Comment: @PranavCBalan do you know how i can do it?

Comment: You need to group all adjacent geoups(with same row) and get the largest among them

Comment: What about jquery solution?

Comment: Whats the jquery solution?

Comment: Same with less code.. will try later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191649/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-john-williams).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you can do something like this.

```js
// get first avalable seat
let $ele = $('.seat.is-available:eq(0)');
//  variable for holding largest range collection
let $maxRange;

// iterate until get empty
while ($ele.length) {
  // extract the id prefix
  let prefix = $ele.data('id').substr(0, $ele.data('id').lastIndexOf('_') + 1);

  // set current range as current element
  let $currentRange = $ele;
  // keep a temporary copy for  iterating
  let $tmp = $currentRange;
  // iterate until there is no adjacent availabe seat is there
  while (($tmp = $tmp.next(`[data-id^="${prefix}"].is-available`)).length)
    // add seat eleemnt to current range
    $currentRange = $currentRange.add($tmp);
  // check previous range and current range and update maxrange acconrdingly
  $maxRange = !$maxRange || $currentRange.length > $maxRange.length ? $currentRange : $maxRange;
  // get next available seat
  $ele = $currentRange.last().nextAll('.seat.is-available').first();
}


console.log($maxRange.map(function() { // extract seat ids
  return $(this).data('id');
}).get())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_11_1"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_11_2"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="20_11_3"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="20_11_4"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_11_5"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_11_6"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="20_11_7"></path>

  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_1"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_2"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_3"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_4"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="20_12_5"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_6"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="20_12_7"></path>

  <path class="seat" data-id="21_1_1"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="21_1_2"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="21_1_3"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="21_1_4"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" data-id="21_1_5"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="21_1_6"></path>
  <path class="seat" data-id="21_1_7"></path>
</svg>
```

**UPDATE :** As you requested, same with `id` attribute.

```js
// get first avalable seat
let $ele = $('.seat.is-available:eq(0)');
//  variable for holding largest range collection
let $maxRange;

// iterate until get empty
while ($ele.length) {
  // extract the id prefix
  let prefix = $ele.attr('id').substr(0, $ele.attr('id').lastIndexOf('_') + 1);

  // set current range as current element
  let $currentRange = $ele;
  // keep a temporary copy for  iterating
  let $tmp = $currentRange;
  // iterate until there is no adjacent availabe seat is there
  while (($tmp = $tmp.next(`[id^="${prefix}"].is-available`)).length){
    // add seat eleemnt to current range
    $currentRange = $currentRange.add($tmp);
    }
  // check previous range and current range and update maxrange acconrdingly
  $maxRange = !$maxRange || $currentRange.length > $maxRange.length ? $currentRange : $maxRange;
  // get next available seat
  $ele = $currentRange.last().nextAll('.seat.is-available').first();
}


console.log($maxRange.map(function() { // extract seat ids
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).get())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <path class="seat" id="20_11_1"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="20_11_2"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" id="20_11_3"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" id="20_11_4"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="20_11_5"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="20_11_6"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" id="20_11_7"></path>

  <path class="seat" id="20_12_1"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="20_12_2"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="20_12_3"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="20_12_4"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" id="20_12_5"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="20_12_6"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="20_12_7"></path>

  <path class="seat" id="21_1_1"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="21_1_2"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" id="21_1_3"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" id="21_1_4"></path>
  <path class="seat is-available" id="21_1_5"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="21_1_6"></path>
  <path class="seat" id="21_1_7"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sorry i think i meffed that up then - is it possible to do it with using standard ids rather then data-id?

Comment: @Johnwilliams : yes it is possible ... Just need to replave .... Data('id') with attr('id') and data-id^= with id^=

Comment: @Johnwilliams :  previously you had missed to update here `console.log($maxRange.map(function() { 
  return $(this).attr('id');
}).get())`